# not able to call muaitc contact api from localhost

Tags: mautic

I am using mautic API for email listing and email sending. I am trying to get all email list with mautic API auth2.0
I am getting access token properly but while i am calling email api like this

```
  $apiUrl = “https://travialist-main.scapp.io”;
  $api = new MauticApi();
  $emailApi = $api->newApi(“emails”, $auth, $apiUrl);
  $emails = $emailApi->getList();
```

its giving me error

> Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [message] => Looks like I encountered an error (error #404). If I do it again, please report me to the system administrator! [code] => 404 [type] => ) ) [error] => Array ( [message] => Looks like I encountered an error (error #404). If I do it again, please report me to the system administrator! (error is deprecated as of 2.6.0 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the errors array instead.) [code] => 404 ) )

Answer (score 0):

I think your $apiUrl should end with /api/. There is an example URL in the comment at https://github.com/mautic/api-library#get-a-context-object